# Question about a null space theorem and its converse.

Tags: linear-algebra

The theorem states (quoted from my book)

"If $x_0$ is any solution of a consistent linear system Ax=b, and if S = {$v_1, v_2, ..., v_k$} is a basis for the null space of A, then every solution of Ax=b can be expressed in the form

$x = x_0 + c_1v_1 + c_2v_2+...+c_kv_k$

Conversely, for all choices of scalars $c_1, c_2, ..., c_k$, the vector x in this formula is a solution of Ax=b."

My question is regarding the converse. Does it imply that for any scalar $c_1, c_2, ..., c_k$ linear combination of Ax=b's null space, there will exist some solution $x_0$ for which $x$ will be a solution of Ax=b (of which $x_0$ is a solution as well)?

My impression from the wording in my book is that: if you have a solution $x_0$ from a consistent linear system Ax=b, then any linear combination of its null space plus $x_0$ will also produce a solution in the same system for which $x_0$ is consistent. I don't believe this interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is saying that for any choice of scalars, and any specific solution to the equation $Ax_0=b$ we have $Ax=b$. In other words, $x$ is a solution to the equation as well, for any choice of scalars.

This is equivalent to saying $Ax=b$ iff $Ax_0=b$. The proof of which can be done by letting $c=c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n$ be vector of size $x_0$. Then $A(x)=A(x_0+c)=Ax_0+Ac=Ax_0+0=Ax_0=b$.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is, I think, correct, though I can't understand what does "...for which $\;x_o\;$ is consistent" can possibly mean within this context.

This is one of the facts that, at least in my case, made get in love even more with mathematics while in university: if we have a non-homogeneous system $\;Ax=b\;$ , for which we know a particular solution $\;x_0\;$ , meaning: $\;Ax_0=b\;$, and if $\;P:=\{\;x\;:\;\;Ax=0\;\}\;$ is the solution subspace of the corresponding homogenoeus system, then the solution set (i.e., **all** the solutions) of the non-homogeneous original system is $\;x_0+P\;$

Comment: yes I understand this fact, It makes perfect sense. My problem is with the wording of the converse. Building off your example, there should be a FINITE amount of solutions for the nonhomogenoeus system for which we have a particular solution $x_0$. The book's wording seems to imply that for any linear combination of P (of which there are an INFINITE many possibilities) $x_0 + P$ will be in the finite solution set of the nonhomogenous system, which $Ax_0 = b$ (this is what I meant). This seems wrong.

Comment: Finite or infinite here depends both on dimension (which is apparently finite since I doubt infinite matrices are introduced in basic linear algebra) and on the field of definition, but yet: any element of $\;P\;$ is a linear combination of any of its basis, and any such lin. comb. added to that particular solution $\;x_0\;$ gives us a solution to the non-homogeneous system, **and each and every solution** of the non-homog. system is gotten in this way. BTW, who decided the non-homog. system has a finite number of solutions, and why?

Comment: Say that if A was a 3x3 matrix that is invertible, then from $x=x_0+c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3$, there can only exist a finite amount of scalars that can define x for a particular $x_0$. (x can only be 2 other values besides $x_0$ in this case). So it wouldn't make sense for all choice of scalars $c_1,c_2,c_3$ for a particular $x_0$ to produce the other two solutions in the system.

Comment: @twenty40, well **yes**: if the matrix is invertible (and thus the systems are square ones), then as a map it is a bijective one and thus there is *only* one preimage for every element in the image (which is everything), so there is **only** the trivial solution for the homogeneous associated system and also one single solution for the non-homogeneous system for every $\;b\neq 0\;$ ...but it is not given even that $\;A\;$ is a square matrix, leave alone invertible !

Answer (score 0):

Your impression is indeed correct.

If $x_0$ is a solution, then $Ax_0 = b$.

As $S$ is a basis of the null space of $A$, any linear combination of the vectors of $S$ is also in the null space of $A$, so $A(c_1x_1 + \cdots + c_k x_k) = 0$.

Then, for $x = x_0 + c_1x_1 + \cdots c_k x_k$, we have:
$Ax = Ax_0 + 0 = b$,
meaning $x$ is also a solution.

Comment: The same thing happens in the case of linear differential equations. If you have any solution of the equation, and a solution of the corresponding homogeneous equation (the one with the same LHS, but RHS zero), then the sum of these two is also a solution of the original equation.